# Correlated random variables and ensembles (law of large numbers?)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, references, ensemble-learning

Consider $n$ i.i.d random variables. By the law of large numbers (LLN) the sample average would converge after some time to the expected value.

Let's assume the random variables are correlated. Would this cause a decrease or increase of the speed of convergence to the sample mean? Or is it not known without some assumptions?

I am actually interested in the case of ensembles. It often suffices training only a few neural networks by cross validation and then averaging the results. Big ensembles give only slight improvements. However, for a precise sample mean I need many more samples (at least my impression). So I observe that the correlations are actually good for speeding up convergence to the "sample mean".

Similarly, probability theory tells us $P(Z \mid X, Y) = P(Z \mid X)$ when two random variables are perfectly correlated. If there is no additional information, then one random variable can be removed. In ML, there is also the [bias-variance-covariance decomposition](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/brown05a/brown05a.pdf), which tells us that diverse ensembles are better.

I am looking for any papers/results/comments that either disprove my impression or put it more into context.